# Convexity of a multivariable function.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, positive-definite

I have the following function :
$f(x,y)=(1-x)^2+10(y-x^2)^2$

To prove that $f(x,y)$ is convex we need to calculate the Hessian matrix :

$\nabla^2f(x,y)=\pmatrix{120x^2-40y+2&-40x \\
-40x&20}$

This function is convex only if : $120x^2-40y+2> 0$ and $det(H)>0$

I'm stuck here and not able to prove $120x^2-40y+2> 0$ and $det(H)>0$.

Comment: Maybe it's not convex everywhere.

Comment: Solve $120x^2-40y+2>0$ for $y$ and then graph that inequality. Do the same for the inequality obtained from the determinant.

Comment: I found $y<x^2+1/20$ for both conditions. How do I interpret that ? @ndhanson3

Comment: You should double check the algebra for when you solved for $y$. That is not correct. Then, sounds like you should review graphing inequalities in general. For example, watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unSBFwK881s